# Forma Correcta de hacer un UPDATE de SQL con PHP y MVC

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, mvc, php8

Buenas lo que estoy tratando de hacer es un **UPDATE** en una de mis tablas de base de datos, se que no lo estoy haciendo bien por como lo tengo estructurado ya que los **INSERT INTO** me salen bien pero el tutorial que estoy siguiendo no habla mucho de los **UPDATE**, así que lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera :

```
<?php

require "Conexion.php";

 class ModeloCerrarCaja{

    static public function mdlCerrarCaja($tabla,$Hora_Cierre,$Total_Ventas,$Estado,$cajaAbierta,$Sucursal){

        if($cajaAbierta!= null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET Hora_Cierre = :$Hora_Cierre, Total_Ventas = :$Total_Ventas, Estado = :$Estado WHERE Sucursal = :$Sucursal AND caja_sucursal = :$cajaAbierta");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":Hora_Cierre", $Hora_Cierre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":Total_Ventas", $Total_Ventas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":Estado", $Estado, PDO::PARAM_STR);


            if($stmt->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
               return "error"; 
            }

        }else{
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;
    }
 }
```

de igual menara si pudieran darme alguna guía base de donde aprender a hacer esta sintaxis correctamente o algún tutorial se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: parece que te faltan dos bindParam,  de $sucursal y de $cajaAbierta...  prueba a ejecutar el mysql_last_error() a ver que te dice de la consulta, dentro del else de error. Te aconsejaria que construyeras la consulta en una variable, y luego se la pasaras al prepare. Asi puedes hacer antes un echo de la consulta, para poder ver como esta escrita

Comment: @Jakala en PDO los errores se obtienen con [el método `errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es preciso que comprendas que **en las consultas preparadas se ponen marcadores, no los valores**.

Por tanto esto es erróneo:

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET Hora_Cierre = :$Hora_Cierre, Total_Ventas = :$Total_Ventas, Estado = :$Estado WHERE Sucursal = :$Sucursal AND caja_sucursal = :$cajaAbierta");
```

Precisamente, el *quid* de una consulta preparada consiste en **poner un marcador en el lugar donde va cada dato** y luego, con un método apropiado (`bindParam` en este caso) pasas el valor para cada dato asociado a su marcador. Es como decirle al controlador: *donde puse este marcador, debes poner este dato, pero revisa que no haya riesgo de inyección*.

Entendido eso, tu código debería quedar así:

```
$sql="UPDATE $tabla SET 
          Hora_Cierre = :Hora_Cierre, 
          Total_Ventas = :Total_Ventas, 
          Estado = :Estado 
       WHERE 
          Sucursal = :Sucursal AND 
          caja_sucursal = :caja_sucursal";
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);
```

Simplemente, hemos quitado toooodas las `$`, teniendo así lo que se requiere, que son **marcadores**.

Ahora, debes decirle al SGBD a qué dato va asociado **cada marcador que pusiste más arriba**, algo MUY IMPORTANTE es que debes escribir cada marcador **exactamente igual que como lo escribiste en la instrucción SQL, y debes vigilar que asocias en cada caso el valor correspondiente y no otro valor**. Por tanto, si estás recibiendo estas variables en parámetro:

```
$Hora_Cierre
$Total_Ventas
$Estado
$cajaAbierta
$Sucursal
```

Debes hacer las vinculaciones **usando esas variables**:

```
$stmt -> bindParam(":Hora_Cierre", $Hora_Cierre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindParam(":Total_Ventas", $Total_Ventas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindParam(":Estado", $Estado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindParam(":Sucursal", $Sucursal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindParam(":caja_sucursal", $cajaAbierta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

No estabas vinculando `:Sucursal` ni `:caja_sucursal`. Yo he asumido que también son cadenas, si alguna no lo es, cambia `PDO::PARAM_STR` por el tipo de dato correcto.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores.

---

#### Advertencia sobre una mala práctica

En tu método, estas dos líneas al final **no se ejecutarán nunca**:

```
$stmt -> close();
$stmt = null;
```

¿Por quéeeee si las he puesto con muy buena intención? Pues porque tienes `return` más arriba y nada lo que esté después de `return` se ejecuta.

Además, son dos líneas redundantes, bastaría con una (de hecho, en algún escenario, no recuerdo ahora si con mysqli o con PDO), invocar a `close()` no me destruía al objeto, `null` en cambio siempre lo destruía.

Quizá una forma mejor de estructurar tu método sería esta:

```
static public function mdlCerrarCaja($tabla,$Hora_Cierre,$Total_Ventas,$Estado,$cajaAbierta,$Sucursal){

    if($cajaAbierta!= null){
        //Consulta UPDATE y demás...

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $mData=array(
                          "success"=>true,
                          "action"=>"update",
                          "data"=>"Filas actualizadas N..."
                         );
        }else{
            $mData=array(
                          "success"=>false,
                          "msg"=>"Error ... Conviene verificar el no de Error con errorInfo() y lanzar tu política de errores"
                         );
        }           
    }else{
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
        $stmt -> execute();
        $mData=array(
                       "success"=>true,
                       "action"=>"read",
                       "data"=>$stmt -> fetchAll()
                    );

    }
    $stmt = null;
    $return $mData;
}
```

Si observas, se ha usado un objeto `$mData` para controlar la lógica interna del método. Devolviendo una clave `success` establecida a `true` cuando haya algún dato o `false` cuando haya algún error.

Dado que este método puede devolver dos tipos de respuestas exitosas, he puesto una clave `action` por la cual podrás distinguir si ocurrió un `update` o un `read` y acoplar en la respuesta: mostrar el mensaje de cantidad de filas actualizadas por ejemplo, o leer los datos del `fetchAll` que obtuviste en el `SELECT`.

En cuanto a los casos de error, cuando `success` sea `false` el mensaje de lo ocurrido se encontrará en una clave `msg`.